# Share code between unit test and instrumentation tests when using kotlin

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, kotlin

Similar question: [Sharing code between Android Instrumentation Tests and Unit Tests in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30627749/sharing-code-between-android-instrumentation-tests-and-unit-tests-in-android-stu)

My setup is the following:

- `src/test` folder that contains unit tests. These can be either Java or Kotlin classes
- `src/androidTest` that contains instrumentation tests. These can also be either Java or Kotlin classes
- `src/sharedTest` is a folder that contains a bunch of utils that are shared between unit and instrumentation tests.

This sharing is defined in gradle as:

```
sourceSets {
    test.java.srcDirs += 'src/sharedTest/java'
    androidTest.java.srcDirs += 'src/sharedTest/java'
}
```

This allows any *Java* class in `src/test` or `src/androidTest` to access the utils. but not the Kotlin unit tests. My assumption is that they are not added to the sourceSets.

My question is: how can I add them? I tried:

```
sourceSets {
    test.kotlin.srcDirs += 'src/sharedTest/java'
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @tynn Not really. Didn't find any info online on whether `test.kotlin.srcDirs` exists or not

Answer (score 1):

The default setup would be making the Kotlin source sets visible to the Java compiler and the IDE as well:

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
        test.java.srcDirs += 'src/test/kotlin'
        test.java.srcDirs += 'src/sharedTest/java'
        androidTest.java.srcDirs += 'src/sharedTest/java'
    }
}
```

You don't need to configure the Kotlin source sets by itself.

Comment: Pretty sure this won't work. I don't have `src/main/kotlin` nor `src/test/kotlin`. What I need is for Kotlin unit tests (who are in `src/test/java`, not `src/test/kotlin`) to be able to access Java clases. Unless you are suggesting that I should move said Kotlin unit tests to `src/test/kotlin`...

Comment: Yes, you should have a different source set for Kotlin. I tried this setup and didn't have any issues. But if you have the Kotlin sources in the Java source set alread, it should have the same effect using the last two lines...

Comment: Alright, I will give it a try, and report back. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your project has both **java** and **kotlin** code the key is to have:

```
src/{folderName}/java
```

and

```
src/{folderName}/kotlin
```

Where {folderName} is: test, androidTest, sharedTest or whatever.

I use:

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        androidTest.java.srcDirs += "src/androidTest/kotlin"
        androidTest.java.srcDirs += "src/sharedTest/java"
        androidTest.java.srcDirs += "src/sharedTest/kotlin"
        test.java.srcDirs += "src/test/kotlin"
        test.java.srcDirs += "src/sharedTest/java"
        test.java.srcDirs += "src/sharedTest/kotlin"
    }
}
```

This is some inconsistency as you can have all java and kotlin code under the same:

```
main/java
```

directory.