# keep mock data accessible only to test and androidTest

Tags: android, unit-testing

I have mock data that I want to use for both unit and instrumented test. To avoid repetition, I created a common directory testHelper and placed my mock data there. In app/build.gradle I did:

```
sourceSets {
    androidTest {
        java.srcDirs += 'testHelper'
    }

    test {
        java.srcDirs += 'testHelper'
    }
}
```

Now i can import my mock data from unit and UI tests but I can also access them from the main app. I want to avoid doing that. I tried a few tips such as adding src/ to the above but it made no difference.

basically, I don't want my main code to access the mock data

```
import AppMockData // ==> this shouldn't work. currently it does.

@Composable
fun HelloWorld(){}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define a new library module (let's call it "common") where you can define all the mock data you need.

The module can be easily created with Android Studio by selecting `New Module` -> `Android Library` and filling out all the data like module name, package name etc.

The mocked data will be located under `common/src/main/java` folder (under your own package name).

Finally, you have to link this new module as dependency in the main app's `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    testImplementation project(':common')
    androidTestImplementation project(':common')
}
```

In this way, your mocked data won't be accessible from your app code.

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks Lino. So where would I put this mock data? Can you give me a few more details please.